# Parent mount becomes inaccessible after mounting child into subdir?

Tags: linux, mount, partition

Im installing arch.  Upon installation, after partitioning my drives, right when I go to chroot to begin the fun stuff, I get an error

```
mount:mount point mnt/etc/resolv.conf does not exist
chroot: failed to run command /bin/sh: no such file or directory.
```

What this error is caused by in my particular case is the `/mnt/etc` filesystem being not available even though it shows as mounted, and was just mounted.

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt
/dev/sda3 /mnt/home
```

I mount `/dev/sda2` to `/mnt` which works and files are accessible. Then I mount `/dev/sda3/` to `/mnt/home`, and BLAM, blows up the mount for `/dev/sda2` `/mnt`.

It still shows up in `# mount`, but when changing directory to /, then back to /mnt, its empty realestate inside all subdirs (proc is existant but empty, etc existent but empty, etc..)

Access was lost just as soon as `dev/sda3` is mounted to `/mnt/home`.
Whats the likely issue here, is it filesystem issues, partition problem maybe, or something lame simple maybe?

Edit: complete sequence of commands being

```
# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/home
# arch-chroot /mnt
#error message shows, i can reboot, its rinse and repeat
```

if i try to mount it to a different dir (the 2nd mount), e.g. /mnt/homey it mounts fine, just the same, which im not sure if i made clear, it mounts fine, just then i lose contents of all dirs inside /mnt, e.g. etc/ becomes empty...

Comment: There is no traditionnal `/etc` filesystem, your question is a bit unclear, can you edit with mount order in a list (e.g. #1 mount /dev/sdX /foo, #2 mount /dev/sdY /bar/baz ... ), along with result of df comment before and after each mount ?

Comment: oops, took off /etc, was a typo brain fart, two of them. and added the new fact that the subdirs are there, but its the subdirs that are empty, e.g. etc is empty.

Comment: Strange, your mount order is cannonical. have you try another mount dir ? (e.g. /mnt2 /mnt2/home ? )

Comment: Your error is referring to a mountpoint named `/mnt/etc/resolv.conf`. There are situations in which it is common to bind-mount something on top of a file like this, but nothing in your question indicates you are doing so.  Can you update your question with the complete sequence of commands you are running before your encounter the problem you have described?

Answer (score 0):

There was alot of random errors, if you notice, and the problem was fairly unforseen.  I was using an old install medium, therefore it was exibiting various bugs, from incompatibilites.  Wow, no wonder that was so hard to troubleshsoot.

i was using arch 2015.01.01

Solution:
Download and use a fresh copy of install medium.